# getting error : Could not find a declaration file for module 'mg-api-js'

Tags: node.js

I am getting error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'mg-api-js'` when i try to import module , i have tried to install it like this way `npm install @types/mg-api-js` but it is also not working, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

```
const GeotabApi  = require('mg-api-js');
const authentication = {
    credentials: {
        database: '**',
        userName: '****',
        password: '****'
    }
}
const api = new GeotabApi(authentication);
```

Comment: What do you have in mg when you do:



**const mg = require('mg-api-js')**

Comment: i have just updated my question

Comment: I did copy and paste your code in a new project with only "mg-api-js" as dependency and that works. Leave only "mg-api-js" as dependency, delete the @types one in package.json,  then delete your node_modules and npm install.
Try those simple steps.

Answer (score 0):

1) remove your node_modules directory and then: `npm install --save mg-api-js`.

2) check your `node_modules/mg-api-js/dist` directory and make sure `api.min.js` exist.

3) if not exist you can clone source code from https://github.com/Geotab/mg-api-js and manually paste to this `node_modules/mg-api-js` direcoty.

4) plz install latest version '2.0.1'

5) see this issue, maybe help you: https://github.com/Geotab/mg-api-js/issues/3

i install this module on windows and work for me.